# How to Get Context of third phase table in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have three Tables

**table1:**

table1id (pk),
table2id (fk)

**table2:**

table2id(pk),
table3id(fk)

**table3:**

table3id(pk)
Name

Can I get the value of a particular Name from table3 using Table1 context in Entity framework?

i.e if I have table1id from that I can get table2id from there context of table3 is it possible to get it?

If yes, how to use it?
Can anyone please give me a way to use it..

**Note :** I don't want to use any Stored Procedure for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mapped the navigational properties correctly you can do that as follows

```
var t3s = context.Table3s
      .Where(t3 => t3.Table2s.Any(t2 => t2.Table1s.Any(t1 => t1.table1id == "foo")))
      .ToList();
```

Comment: i want to bind these data in the grid where i want to get the name field of table3 so this is to get only 1 record how to find multiple records using this query u have provided me???

Comment: @Smith.Patel remove the `.FirstOrDefault()` part :)

Comment: but how to get all the records?? :)

Comment: what is the "Foo" here? is it for searching a particular record or something else.. can u please explain me how to use it.. :)

Comment: @Smith.Patel That is the `table1id` value that you use to filter. Replace that with your variable of choice.